# How do I upload new release without Install Package Request: Android App?

Tags: android, flutter, performance, package, auto-update

I have removed the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission from the new release and am trying to update my App on Google to replace the version which had the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission. The app does not require REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission so I have not completed the policy statement. How do I update my app to deactivate the version with the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission and not have Google remove it? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.